# Split data into multiple html tables according to a group in jsp

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a big data table which has to be split into smaller tables in jsp. The tables would be created according to group type. Have spent hours trying to figure it out but unable to filter the list in the jsp as per fruit type group.

```
     @RequestMapping(value = { "dynamicFruitSettings" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView getDynamicComponents( Model model) {

        LOG.debug("Entering fruit components page");
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

        ArrayList<DynamicFruitSettings> resultList = null;
            try {
                resultList = (ArrayList<DynamicFruitSettings>) dynamicFruitService.loadAllFruitComponents();
                mav.addObject(resultList);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return new ModelAndView("fruitComponents" , "listFruitComponents", resultList);
        }




        @Entity
        @Table(name = "fruits_components")
        public class DynamicFruitSettings {

        /** The pk1. */
        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "fruits_components_seq", sequenceName = "fruits_components_seq", allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "fruits_components_seq")


        private Long pk1;

        private String fruit_type;
        private String component_role;
        private Double fruit_wt;

        //getters and setters omitted for brevity
```

**Sample that shows all data in jsp**

```css
/* DivTable.com */

.divTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell,
.divTableHead {
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableFoot {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableHeading">&nbsp;Fruits</div>
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;shake</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;10</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;ice cream</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;20</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;cake</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;40</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;candy</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;shake</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;13</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;ice cream</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;30</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;cake</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;90</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;candy</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;25</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;shake</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;19</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;ice cream</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;20</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;cake</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;40</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;candy</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;15</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Final look in the jsp should be something like the below

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell,
.divTableHead {
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableFoot {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableHeading">Banana</div>
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;shake</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;10</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;ice cream</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;20</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;cake</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;40</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;candy</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableHeading">&nbsp;Peach</div>
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;shake</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;13</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;ice cream</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;30</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;cake</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;90</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;candy</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;25</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableHeading">&nbsp;Apple</div>
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;shake</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;19</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;ice cream</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;20</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;cake</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;40</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;candy</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;15</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
```

The sample that shows all data is what I get currently in my jsp. I get this list of fruits together from my Controller which gets the data from the fruits table in db. As the fruit type could be anything, I cannot do a simple "for each" loop on fruits based on pk1 and then do a "if" clause to render it into the jsp. Every row has a pk1 in the database table.

Your suggestions as to how I should split them into smaller tables would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Also, if I can get a list of unique group fruit types in the jsp so that I can do the if clause within a for loop to render the tables, I should be closer to a solution.

Comment: Why don't you send different lists for each fruit type from controller itself that will be more easy

Comment: @Vivek Kumar, the fruit types are coming from dynamically entered form data. They can be n number of fruit types. Therefore, am not sure how sending different fruit type lists help in displaying all fruit types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the data to be split into dynamic tables by altering my Controller as to how I send the data to my jsp. Instead of sending the data as a list, am sending it across as a  map of lists. In that way, I am able to loop the map, get the key as a group and display the values which is the list.

Therefore the problem is solved.

I have a different problem which would be posted as a new question with respect to duplicating data (i.e., the list values in the jsp that act as my table rows) which keep getting added on every refresh of the page with no duplicate rows in db that I find very weird. The duplicates get removed from the jsp only if I restart my application.